# How is Grover's algorithm used in reducing duration of time taken to brute-force a hash?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

I read somewhere on internet that **brute-forcing** a hash on classical computer will take time proportional to the length of data. But somehow if one have **possible inputs** used, using **Grover's algorithm**, one can reduce time significantly. So, is this statement **true** ? If yes how **Grover's algorithm** do that and it reduces the **brute-force time** by how much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this statement is true. If there are $N$ possible items to check, the classical brute force method takes time $O(N)$. Grover's search only takes time $O(\sqrt{N}$). More precisely, if you want to have a probability of at least $1-1/N$, the classical algorithm has to check $N$ possibilities. The quantum algorithm has to perform $$\left\lfloor\frac{\pi}{4\arcsin(1/\sqrt{N})}\right\rfloor$$
checks. Whether the quantum checks take the same length of time as the classical checks, in order to make a fair "real world" comparison is not usually considered; it's just done by counting the number of checks (often described as "calls to the oracle").

*How* is another question entirely - unless you're happy with the answer "mysterious quantum mumbo-jumbo", there's quite a lot of prerequisite studying to get you to a place where you can understand the answer.